# Data Lost while creating bins using python pandas cut function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My objective is to transfer one column from df1 to df2 and at the same time creating bins.I have dataframe named df1 which include 3 numerical variables. I want to fetch one variable named 'tenure' to df2 and want to create bins.It transfer column values to df2 but df2 shows some missing values.
please find code below :

```
df2=pd.cut(df1["tenure"] , bins=[0,20,60,80], labels=['low','medium','high'])
```

before creating df2 I checked for missing values in df1. there was not such mussing values but after creating bins it shows 11 missing values.

```
print(df2.isnull().sum())
```

Above Code shows 11 missing values

Anyones help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have some values in `df1['tenure']` that are not in `(0,80]`, maybe the zeros. See the example below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'tenure':[-1, 0, 12, 34, 78, 80, 85]})
print (pd.cut(df1["tenure"] , bins=[0,20,60,80], labels=['low','medium','high']))

0       NaN    # -1 is lower than 0 so result is null
1       NaN    # it was 0 but the segment is open on the lowest bound so 0 gives null
2       low
3    medium
4      high
5      high    # 80 is kept as the segment is closed on the right
6       NaN    # 85 is higher than 80 so result is null
Name: tenure, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [low < medium < high]
```

Now, you can pass the parameter `include_lowest=True` in `pd.cut` to keep the left bound in the result:

```
print (pd.cut(df1["tenure"] , bins=[0,20,60,80], labels=['low','medium','high'],
              include_lowest=True))

0       NaN
1       low  # now where the value was 0 you get low and not null
2       low
3    medium
4      high
5      high
6       NaN
Name: tenure, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [low < medium < high]
```

So finally, I think that if you print `len(df1[(df1.tenure <= 0) | (df1.tenure > 80)])` you will get 11 with your data as the number of `null` values in your `df2` (here it is 3 with my data)